# Android: First ListView element is under the TitelBar

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a problem with my titleBar and I freak out. When I run the project in the Android virtual machine everything looks fine but on the device the first element of my ListView disappear under the titleBar. Same thing with my Drawer on the virtual machine everything is fine, on the device the first two elements are under the titleBar.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_idea"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    tools:context="***">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: why you are using these lines as parent of ListView is LinearLayour
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this in listview

```
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
```

Comment: This works but it feels not right to set a static padding.

Comment: And the Drawer issue is not solved by setting the listview padding. It's seems that the Layout don't know that there is a titelbar.